How to set up Apache Impala on Windows using Docker?
Can anyone help me with a step-by-step guide or a docker-compose.yml file that can be used to set up Apache Impala with its required services (e.g., Impala Daemon, State Store, Catalog Service, HDFS) in Docker containers?
I need to know the following:

How to set up HDFS (either using hadoop or a similar service) in Docker.
How to configure Impala to connect to HDFS and run queries.
What specific Docker images to use for Impala and HDFS.
Any important environment variables or configurations that need to be set for Impala to work properly.
How to expose necessary ports (e.g., for Impala Daemon) on Windows.


https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Use a VM (i.e. Vagrant) for this. Yarn is needed for Impala. Yarn runs (JVM, or Docker) containers. Containers, in general, don't run well within (Docker) containers as you're just slicing your (virtualized) host into smaller pieces. In other words, you're not distributing anything.
Otherwise, look into alternative solutions like Spark Connect / Thrift Server, FlinkSQL, or Trino. Alternatively, Hive LLAP should perform comparatively to Impala for small scale workloads.

How to set up HDFS (either using hadoop or a similar service) in Docker... What specific Docker images to use

Look at apache/hadoop in Dockerhub... Or Ozone
You expose ports the same way as any other container
